# Spark SQL table partition File Not Found

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark cluster which I use to run a Spark SQL application. I am trying the Spark SQL feature of table partition. When I am ingesting the data, I am getting a file not found exception stating that a file X does not exist, that file is related to the data I am ingesting. That behaviour only happens with some specific fields of a table, for other fields I am able to successfully insert the data and query it later. Another observation is that if I turn off the remote workers, the ingestion works fine for any field. I am using Spark 2.2, Standalone mode. I dont have a distributed file system in place, I synchronise the files manually after the ingestion is done. Anyone have an idea of why that behaviour occurs?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be because you don't have HDFS. If you have HDFS when a worker node takes the task, the files are available to them. because you dont have HDFS, when the task is passed over to Worker nodes, they dont see the location where they are supposed to read the data from.

I would say you should use HDFS or have NFS mount so that all nodes have access to the same files regardless of where the worker node is.

I hope this helps.